# Count same rows

Tags: excel

I have a form with three questions. Answers are exported to Excel and they look like this:

1. answer in column B:

   name 1
   name 2
   name 3
   name 4
   name 5
2. answer in column C:

   name 11
   name 12
   name 13
   name 14
   name 15
3. answer in column D:

   name 21
   name 22

In all three questions there are more names to choose and users have to choose 5 names (in third question only two names).

Is there any way to show how namy times was each name chosen? and make a chart sorted by most votes for every question

EDIT:
one answer is in one cell, so there are cells with more rows

Comment: Yup you can use Pivottables for that

Comment: SO is about programming and I can't find anything related to programming in question. Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) - another stack exchange site

Comment: @pnuts: No worries :) I make these mistakes too :P

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout of the source then (as @Siddharth Rout suggested!) you can use you a PivotTable to summarise the results and to plot a chart:

[image: SO18740440 example]

[Anybody inclined to upvote is invited to find one of Siddharth's answers and +1 there!]

Comment: I forgot to mention, that every answer is in one cell.